# How to count the number of checked Checkboxes with Rules?

Tags: commerce, taxonomy-terms, rules, userpoints

I have a [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) site which uses [user points](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints) (= coins) for paying.

I have a special case - the product, which the user should buy with his/her coins, needs some fields filled out by the user. So I used a content type for this case and when the user adds a new one, 10 coins will be reduced from the user's account - this works already fine.

Now I have also a taxonomy in this content type and the user can add terms to it, which are shown later in the form when the user fills it.

**Problem :**

I need to count how many checkboxes of the taxonomy terms are checked and multiply the costs with them. So if 3 of 5 are checked, then 10 coins * 3 = 30 coins will be the final price when the user adds a new content type.

Is this possible with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)? I have no clue how to realize that
(I´m front-end developer and no PHP coder).

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, was not able to test it yet because the project got postponed.

Comment: sorry, had to google how to accept an answer, i´m a totally stackexchange newbie

Comment: merci for the accept ... maybe you were looking for http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is perfectly possible with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), and you don't need any PHP to get the job done. In your case, the crucial part of such rule is a Rules Action to perform a **Loop**. If you're not familiar with such loops, then I strongly recommend to have a look at the tutorial titled "[Lists and loops](http://drupal.placeto.be/tutorial/lists-and-loops)".

In your case, you should use (at least) these Rules Actions:

- "Add a variable" (say with a machine name like `nr_of_checked_terms`), with initial value "0".
- Add a loop related to your taxonomy terms. After you do, you should iterate over each item in that list (= each taxonomy term). And for each iteration you should then perform a Rules Action to "Set a data value", whereas you actually increment the value of `nr_of_checked_terms` with "1".

After the loop finished, the value of `nr_of_checked_terms` will be the actual number of terms that were checked. Just add another Rules Action near the end to do your actual multiplication using `nr_of_checked_terms` as one of the available tokens.

***Done***

PS 1: Refer to my answer to "[How to set multiple values to an unlimited Term Refence field with Rules](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/220892/how-to-set-multiple-values-to-an-unlimited-term-refence-field-with-rules/220894#220894)" for some sample rules that are like a variation of your question here.

PS 2: I assume this is about D7 ...

Comment: hi, thanks a lot for your answer, yes, it was about D7